# Free Notes App for Windows 10 with note folders

Tags: windows, gratis, note-taking

There is an app called **Notebooks** (http://www.notebooksapp.com/), which has basically everything I need (Check the image bellow). Still, this app is not free, and I wonder if there is a similar **free** app for windows 10.

The functionality I need is:

- Notes organized in a tree, like it is shown in the image, you can organize your notes so that they belong to a specific category.
- Keep it simple, I just need to writte plain text symbols, nothing more complicated. Pasting an image is usefull but not a must.

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Ever tried TagSpaces?

Answer (score 2):

From [my favo(u)rite site](https://www.techsupportalert.com) for reviews & rated free software, comes one that I used for many years, until I needed something more complex. See [thsi page](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-outliner.htm) for more.

[KeyNote NF](https://sourceforge.net/projects/keynote-newfeat/)

Pro: User friendly, multi-level notes, tabbed interface, richtext editor, strong encryption, per-file configurations, hidden nodes, alarms on nodes, multiple backups and more.

Con: Single platform, inserting images in bmp and gif formats but jpg format surprisingly excluded.

[image]

.
[image]
.